# Is gzip format supported in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, mapreduce, gzip, apache-spark

For a Big Data project, I'm planning to use [spark](http://spark-project.org/docs/latest/index.html), which has some nice features like in-memory-computations for repeated workloads. It can run on local files or on top of HDFS.

However, in the official documentation, I can't find any hint as to how to process gzipped files. In practice, it can be quite efficient to process .gz files instead of unzipped files.

Is there a way to manually implement reading of gzipped files or is unzipping already automatically done when reading a .gz file?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From the Spark Scala Programming guide's [section on "Hadoop Datasets"](http://spark-project.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html#hadoop-datasets):

> Spark can create distributed datasets from any file stored in the Hadoop distributed file system (HDFS) or other storage systems supported by Hadoop (including your local file system, Amazon S3, Hypertable, HBase, etc). Spark supports text files, SequenceFiles, and any other Hadoop InputFormat.

Support for gzip input files should work the same as it does in Hadoop.  For example, `sc.textFile("myFile.gz")` should automatically decompress and read gzip-compressed files (`textFile()` is actually [implemented](https://github.com/mesos/spark/blob/v0.7.0/core/src/main/scala/spark/SparkContext.scala#L239) using Hadoop's `TextInputFormat`, which supports gzip-compressed files).

As mentioned by @nick-chammas in the comments:

> note that if you call `sc.textFile()` on a gzipped file, Spark will give
>   you an RDD with only 1 partition (as of 0.9.0). This is because
>   gzipped files are [not splittable](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201310.mbox/%3CCANDWdjY2hN-=jXTSNZ8JHZ=G-S+ZKLNze=RGkJacJAW3tTOQQA@mail.gmail.com%3E). If you don't repartition the RDD
>   somehow, any operations on that RDD will be limited to a single core

Comment: When I try `logs = sc.textFile("logs/*.bz2")`, I get an error on subsequent `logs.count()`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @zbinsd have you figured it out at the end? I'm getting the following error when loading tar.gz files: JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens

Comment: @Leon, from this page: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html, it says: All of Spark’s file-based input methods, including textFile, support running on directories, compressed files, and wildcards as well. For example, you can use textFile("/my/directory"), textFile("/my/directory/*.txt"), and textFile("/my/directory/*.gz")

I hope that helps.

Comment: I am trying to process something from Google Takeout, but it is one file (.mbox) I want from inside an archive. How can I specify that I want this one file?

Comment: It seems the spark checks for the ```.gz``` file extension for compressed files. I had a compressed file which is read well with ```sc.textFile()``` but returns byte strings when I mess around with the extension thus, ```somefile.gz.bkp```