# How to read binary-protobuf gz files in Spark / Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, gzip, protocol-buffers

I have to read the gz file from local / hdfs / kafka, and decompress it and parse it. Who have any experiences about this?

Or the other type likes bin.tar.gz

Comment: This may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302385/gzip-support-in-spark

Comment: Yes, I have read it. But it looks like that it only support text type. Especially, If the gz file is combined severals bin files?

Comment: I could correct deserialize the bin data. But there is no method for the gz file.

Comment: Hi @steven, got any headway with the reading of the protobuf gz files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sc.binaryFiles` to read binary files and do whatever you like with the content bytes.

As for tar.gz, see [Read whole text files from a compression in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604145/read-whole-text-files-from-a-compression-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:
1. read binary data = sc.binaryFiles(path)
2. extract content

```
data = (data
        .map(lambda x: (x[0], ungzip(x[1])))
        )


def ungzip(df):
    compressed_file = io.BytesIO(df)
    decompressed_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_file)

    return decompressed_file.read()
```

3. parse messages

def _VarintDecoder(mask):

```
    local_ord = ord

    def DecodeVarint(buffer, pos):
        result = 0
        shift = 0
        while 1:
            if pos > len(buffer) - 1:
                raise NotEnoughDataExcption("Not enough data to decode varint")
            b = local_ord(buffer[pos])
            result |= ((b & 0x7f) << shift)
            pos += 1
            if not (b & 0x80):
                result &= mask
                return (result, pos)
            shift += 7
            if shift >= 64:
                raise ValueError('Too many bytes when decoding varint.')

    return DecodeVarint
```

.

```
def parse_binary(data):
    decoder = _VarintDecoder((1 << 64) - 1)
    next_pos, pos = 0, 0
    messages = []
    try:
        while 1:
            next_pos, pos = decoder(data[1], pos)
            messages.append((data[0], data[1][pos:pos + next_pos]))
            pos += next_pos
    except:
        return messages
```

.

```
data = (data
        .flatMap(lambda x: parse_binary(x))
        )
```

after this you have you protobuf messages one per row and you can apply your protobuf_parsing function in parallel