# How to extract a bz2 file in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compression

I have a csv file zipped in bz2 format, like unix/linux do we have any single line command to extrac/decompress the file file.csv.bz2 to file.csv in spark-scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use built in function in SparkContext(sc), this worked for me

```
sc.textFile("file.csv.bz2").saveAsTextFile("file.csv")
```

Comment: And if you then just need to save the uncompressed file after you can use saveAsTextFile: `sc.textFile("file.csv.bz2").saveAsTextFile("file.csv")`

Comment: yes, it serves the purpose, I will edit the answer @puhlen