# how to get all csv files in tar directory that contains csv.gz directory using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, rdd, tar, gzip

I have the following problem: suppose that I have a directory containing compressed directories .tar which contain multiple file .csv.gz.  I want to get all csv.gz files in the parent compressed directorie *.tar. I work with scala 2.11.7 
this tree

```
   file.tar
       |file1.csv.gz
             file11.csv
       |file2.csv.gz
             file21.csv
       |file3.csv.gz
             file31.csv
```

I want to get from file.tar a list of files : file1.csv.gz , file2.csv.gz file3.csv.gz so after that a can create dataframe from each file csv.gz to do some transformation.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: hello @Robert I tried to read from gz files to a dataframe using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635905/reading-in-multiple-files-compressed-in-tar-gz-archive-into-spark) it works but I want to get a list of name of files because i'll read each file into a specific dataframe.