# how to decompress and read a file containing multiple compressed file in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a file AA.zip which again contains multiple files for ex aa.tar.gz, bb.tar.gz , etc

I need to read this files in spark scala , how can i achieve that??

the only problem here is to extract the contents of zip file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read whole text files from a compression in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604145/read-whole-text-files-from-a-compression-in-spark)

Comment: no, that question is about a directory containing compressed files but here i have a file which is in zip format and again contains files with .tar.gz format.

Answer (score 0):

so ZIPs on HDFS are going to be a bit tricky because they don't split well so you'll have to process 1 or more zip file per executor. This is also one of the few cases were you probably have to fall back to `SparkContext` because for some reason binary file support in Spark is not that good.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext

there's a `readBinaryFiles` there which gives you access to the zip binary data which you can then utilize with the usual ZIP-handling from java or scala.