# Read data from XML files which are zipped in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a scenario where I have to read multiple XML files which are zipped together in PySpark.

Zip File Size: 30 GB

Size When Unzipped: 600 GB

Max size of a single file: 40 GB

Time taken to extract: 4 Hours

I am able to read the extracted XML data with the predefined schema using databricks API. But lot of time is consumed in extracting the data itself. Is there a way to read data from the zip file directly rather than extracting it?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: @ForceBru: I am more concerned about reading in spark rather than using native Python. As far as I understand, both the questions are different.

Comment: Is it  600 GB in a single file?

Comment: No Multiple files

Comment: See [Read whole text files from a compression in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36604145/10465355).

Comment: How are they zipped? Gzip?

Comment: Windows zipped file *.zip