# pyspark to read compressed files without extracting it

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I see similar questions with Java/Scala, but how to import files compressed in a zip/gzip/tar format in pyspark, without the actual decompression?

I would like to hear suggestions on 1) how to get a list of files in one compressed file, 2) how to read each one into a spark dataframe using pyspark. The output I look for is a list of filename:dataframe object where the dataframe is the content of each file.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read whole text files from a compression in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604145/read-whole-text-files-from-a-compression-in-spark)

Comment: Why do you not want to extract the archive, is there a strong reason not to do so?

Comment: @OliverW. The compressed file could contain a large number of files that are not needed at all. Can catalyst optimize the process in this case?

Comment: @OliverW. I would like to see an array of  filename:dataframe object as the output. I don't get it from the question you pointed.