# Extracting tar.gz on databricks

Tags: pyspark, extract, tar, databricks

I'm trying to extract a tar.gz of around 5 gig (contents around 35) on our databricks environment.
I have tried to extract it with :

```
tar = tarfile.open(blob_storage_location', 'r:gz')
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Also copied it to our databricks environment and tried it then.

Also tried:

```
%sh
tar xvzf $(find /dbfs/tmp/ -name '*.tar.gz' -print ) -C /dbfs/tmp/
```

And:

`shutil.unpack_archive(path, path, gz)`

They all start and then keep hanging. Only when I use our biggest default cluster it works but I feel that it should work a smaller cluster as well (since it works on my laptop).

Difference clusters:

- cluster 1

  - Worker Type:

    - 14.0 GB Memory, 4 Cores, 0.75 DBU Standard_DS3_v2
    - Min Workers 2 Max Workers 8
- cluster 2

  - Worker Type:

    - 28.0 GB Memory, 4 Cores, 1 DBU Standard_DS3_v2
    - Workers 8

Any advice to get it working on the smaller one would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I found this question back again and found the answer. You can create a custom cluster for this with just a single node. Then it will work fine.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61749827/2126910) it seems like Databricks can't handle extracting tar files.

Answer (score 1):

when you use `%sh` or any of the Python libraries, it doesn't matter how many workers do you have - the work is done only on the driver node.
I suspect that the problem is that you have many files and unpacking data to DBFS could be a bottleneck.

I would recommend to try to unpack data to the local disk first, and then move unpacked files to DBFS.

```sh
tar xvzf /dbfs/..../file.tar.gz -C /tmp/unpacked
```

and then move:

```py
dbutils.fs.mv("file:/tmp/unpacked", "dbfs:/tmp/", True)
```