# decompress (unzip/extract) util using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have customer_input_data.tar.gz in HDFS, which have 10 different  tables data in csv file format. so i need to unzip this file to /my/output/path  using spark scala

please suggest how to unzip customer_input_data.tar.gz file using spark scala

Comment: Try to follow this link, it could give you some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604145/read-whole-text-files-from-a-compression-in-spark

Comment: thanks for sending useful link. working on my won solution. will update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed the below code for decompress the files using scala. You need to pass input path and output path and Hadoopfile system

```
    /*below method used for processing zip files*/
  @throws[IOException]
  private def processTargz(fullpath: String, houtPath: String, fs: FileSystem): Unit = {
    val path = new Path(fullpath)
    val gzipIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(fs.open(path))
    try {
      val tarIn = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzipIn)
      try {
        var entry:TarArchiveEntry = null
        out.println("Tar entry")
        out.println("Tar Name entry :" + FilenameUtils.getName(fullpath))
        val fileName1 = FilenameUtils.getName(fullpath)
        val tarNamesFolder = fileName1.substring(0, fileName1.indexOf('.'))
        out.println("Folder Name : " + tarNamesFolder)
        while ( {
          (entry = tarIn.getNextEntry.asInstanceOf[TarArchiveEntry]) != null
        }) { // entity Name as tsv file name which are part of inside compressed tar file
          out.println("ENTITY NAME : " + entry.getName)

          /** If the entry is a directory, create the directory. **/
          out.println("While")
          if (entry.isDirectory) {
            val f = new File(entry.getName)
            val created = f.mkdir
            out.println("mkdir")
            if (!created) {
              out.printf("Unable to create directory '%s', during extraction of archive contents.%n", f.getAbsolutePath)
              out.println("Absolute path")
            }
          }
          else {
            var count = 0
            val slash = "/"
            val targetPath = houtPath + slash + tarNamesFolder + slash + entry.getName
            val hdfswritepath = new Path(targetPath)
            val fos = fs.create(hdfswritepath, true)
            try {
              val dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_SIZE)
              try {
                val data = new Array[Byte](BUFFER_SIZE)
                while ( {
                  (count = tarIn.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1
                }) dest.write(data, 0, count)
              } finally if (dest != null) dest.close()
            }
          }
        }
        out.println("Untar completed successfully!")
      } catch {
        case e: IOException =>
          out.println("catch Block")
      } finally {
        out.println("FINAL Block")
        if (tarIn != null) tarIn.close()
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`gzip` is not a `splittable` format in Hadoop. Consequently, the file is not really going to be distributed across the cluster and you don't get any benefit of distributed compute/processing in hadoop or Spark.

Better approach may be to,

- uncompress the file on the OS and then individually send the files back to hadoop.

If you still want to uncompress in scala, you can simply resort to java class `GZIPInputStream` via

```java
new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("your file path"))
```