# Filtering files using specific pattern when reading tar.gz archive in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, gzip, tar

I have multiple CSV files in my folder `myfolder.tar.gz`. Which I created in this way: first put all my files in a folder name `myfolder` then prepare a `tar` folder of it. Then prepare `.gz` of that tar folder.

Let us say we have 5 files.

```
abc_1.csv
abc_2.csv
abc_3.csv
def_1.csv
def_2.csv
```

I want to filter read files in a specific filename pattern using Pyspark data frame. Like we want to read all `abc` files together.

This should not give us the results from `def` and vice versa. Currently, I am able to read all the CSV files together by just using `spark.read.csv()` function. Also, I am able to filter file when I keep the files in a simple folder using `pathGlobalFilter` parameter like this:

```
df = spark.read.csv("mypath",pathGlobalFilter="def_[1-9].csv")
```

But when I am able to do the same in `tar.gz`, like:

```
df = spark.read.csv("myfolder.tar.gz", pathGlobalFilter="def_[1-9].csv")
```

I am getting an error:

> Unable to infer Schema for CSV. How to read from .tar.gz file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36707257/1386551), you can read the `.tar.gz` file as `binaryFile` then using python `tarfile` you can extract the archive members and filter on file names using the regex `def_[1-9]`. The result is an rdd that you can convert into a data frame :

```
import re
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO

# extract only the files with which math regex 'def_[1-9].csv'
def extract_files(bytes):
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(bytes), mode="r:gz")
    return [tar.extractfile(x).read() for x in tar if re.match(r"def_[1-9].csv", x.name)]

# read binary file and convert to df
rdd = sc.binaryFiles("/path/myfolder.tar.gz") \
        .mapValues(extract_files) \
        .flatMap(lambda row: [x.decode("utf-8").split("\n") for x in row[1]])\
        .flatMap(lambda row: [e.split(",") for e in row])

df = rdd.toDF(*csv_cols)
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I am trying to run the code and trying to print anything inside extract_files function, it is not printing anything. Also rdd.count() is showing 0.

Comment: @supernova I tested it with CSV files having the names provided in your question and I was able to get the desired result. Make sure the files in the `tar.gz` archive respect naming regex `def_[1-9].csv`.  To print the names of the file, you can modifiy the `extract_files` to return `return [x.name for x in tar]` and collect the rdd like this `print(sc.binaryFiles("/path/myfolder.tar.gz") .mapValues(extract_files).collect())`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I was having problem with regex expression. Now it is working. Also instead of mapValues(extract_files) , in Pyspark, I need to call function like this mapValues(lambda x : extract_files(x)). Now it is working fine. Thanks again.